# Join two character dataframe with bind_rows function in R

Tags: r, dplyr

i want to bind_rows two dataframe. I have tried lots solution, but no one gives me a good results.

df1 <-

```
id      |   data1   |   data2   |   data3   |   data4
1       |   pl-lo   |   pl      |   lo      |   lo
2       |   lo      |   st-lo   |   pl      |   pl
3       |   pl      |   lo      |           |   
4       |           |           |   pl-pa   |   lo
5       |   st-lo   |   pl      |   st      |   pl-lo
```

df2<-

```
id      |   data1   |   data2   |   data3   |   data4   | data5
1       |   pl      |   lo      |   st      |   pl      |   pl
6       |   pl      |           |   pl      |   pl      |   st
7       |   lo      |   lo      |   lo      |           |
4       |           |           |           |   lo      |
3       |   st      |   pl      |   st      |   pl      |   pl
```

I want to get this output

```
id      |   data1   |   data2   |   data3   |   data4   |   data5
1       |   pl-lo-pl|   pl-lo   |   lo-st   |   lo-pl   |   pl
2       |   lo      |   st-lo   |   pl      |   pl      |   
3       |   pl-st   |   lo-pl   |   st      |   pl      |   pl
4       |           |           |   pl-pa   |   lo-lo   |
6       |   pl      |           |   pl      |   pl      |   st
7       |   lo      |   lo      |   lo      |           |
```

I tride this, but it gives me a wrong output

```
 outpud <<- bind_rows (df1, df2) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise_if(.,is.character,funs(paste0(.,collapse = "-" )))
```

Comment: What is the `good result`?

Comment: I want to get the described output

Comment: This is merging the data partially. Which columns are you using? Can you explain how the two columns become the last one? Just to get an idea. (It is not rbinding)

Comment: I want to join two dataframe which contain strings and grouped by username. If the tow dataframe contains the same col I want to concat two strings, if it is contained different columns then I will add the new col the output.

Answer (score 1):

assuming your empty values are NA, you can use a `mutate_all` after the `summarise_if` to remove the concatenated NA's.

```
bind_rows (df1, df2) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise_if(.,is.character, funs(paste0(.,collapse = "-" ))) %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(stringr::str_replace_all(., "NA-|-NA|NA", "")))


# A tibble: 7 x 6
  id    data1    data2 data3 data4 data5
  <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1     pl-lo-pl pl-lo lo-st lo-pl pl   
2 2     lo       st-lo pl    pl    ""   
3 3     pl-st    lo-pl st    pl    pl   
4 4     ""       ""    pl-pa lo-lo ""   
5 5     st-lo    pl    st    pl-lo ""   
6 6     pl       ""    pl    pl    st   
7 7     lo       lo    lo    ""    ""
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

col1 <- colnames(mtcars)

col2 <- colnames(mtcars)


mtcars3 <- mtcars %>% 
          mutate(names = rownames(mtcars)) %>% 
          group_by(names)
#remove one to show what happens when you have a missing level
mtcars5 <- filter(mtcars3, names != "Mazda RX4") %>% 
            arrange(names)
#keeps only the same in both dataframes 
mtcars7 <- inner_join(mtcars3,select(mtcars5,names), by='names') %>% 
            arrange(names) 


#paste columns together
mtcars9 <- as.data.frame(mapply(paste,mtcars5[col1], mtcars7[col2], MoreArgs = list(sep="-")),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#rename names (also duplicates)
mtcars9$names <- mtcars5$names
#get solo column that was not in both dfs
mtcars10 <- anti_join(mtcars3,mtcars5, by='names')
#bind on
mtcars11 <- bind_rows(mtcars9,sapply(mtcars10,as.character))
```